# When would you use optional<not_null<T*>>

Tags: c++, notnull, stdoptional

I was reading [References, simply](https://herbsutter.com/2020/02/23/references-simply/) and got to the part talking about using optional references. One of the reasons Herb gives to avoid `optional<T&>` is because those situations can be "represented about equally well by `optional<not_null<T*>>`"

I'm confused about when you would ever want `optional<not_null<T*>>`. In my mind, the `optional` cancel's out the `not_null`, so why wouldn't you just use a raw pointer in a case like this.

Comment: if you want to interact with code that expects optionals and not_nulls. If it's all your own code, then you can choose to just use T*

Comment: Replacing `optional<T&>` by `T*` has the disadvantage that `T*` is not meaningful, it could be owning or not, it might be a single object or an array. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T*` doesn't have any member functions, whereas `optional<not_null<T*>>` has a bunch.

What I'd like is to be able to compose functions like

```
auto result = maybe_A()
    .transform(A_to_B)
    .and_then(B_to_opt_C)
    .or_else({});
```

which should be equivalent to

```
optional<A&> first = maybe_A();
optional<B&> second = first.transform(A_to_B);
optional<C&> third = second.and_then(B_to_opt_C);
C result = third.or_else({});
```

With pointers, we can't do that as one expression.

```
A* first = maybe_A();
B* second = first ? A_to_B(*first) : nullptr;
C* third = second ? B_to_opt_C(*second) : nullptr;
C result = third ? *third : {};
```

Whereas at least with `optional<not_null<T*>>` we can adapt our functions

```
optional<not_null<A*>> first = maybe_A();
optional<not_null<B*>> second = first.transform([](not_null<A*> a){ return &A_to_B(*a); });
optional<not_null<C*>> third = second.and_then([](not_null<B*> b){ return B_to_opt_C(*b); });
C result = third.or_else({});
```

a.k.a

```
auto result = maybe_A()
    .transform([](not_null<A*> a){ return &A_to_B(*a); })
    .and_then([](not_null<B*> b){ return B_to_opt_C(*b); })
    .or_else({});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason you might want `optional<optional<T>>`.

At some level you code operates with value which might exist or not. Hence `optional`.

Value type of that optional value can be `T`, `not_null<T>`, `nullable<T>` or anything else, it does not matter to that code. It just checks for value existence and possibly pass it to some other fucntions.

Those functions represent some other level of code. They can accept their arguments from functions unwrapping `optional`, taking address of its member, etc. They have own preconditions: argument should be pointer, and it should not be null. Hence `not_null<T*>`.

In the end, you get `optional<not_null<T*>>`, because some code expects `not_null<T*>`, and other wants to take whatever first want and wrap it in `optional`.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember the context of the suggestion. The problem that `optional<T&>` would solve is cases where a user may or may not have a `T`, but if they do, they want you to modify it in some way while still retaining access to it. *And* that you want to use the `optional` interface to handle the "not a value" case.

So if you want to use the `optional` interface (and therefore `T*` isn't an option), and `optional<T&>` is not available by fiat, then you could use `optional<T*>` as a substitute. But technically that means that the `optional` could have a "value" which is `nullptr`. So instead, you use a type that explicitly forbids `nullptr`: `optional<not_null<T*>>`.

Basically, the suggestion is there to say that you can get the effects of `optional<T&>` without the problems that such a type tends to bring.

Comment: `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` would be another alternative.